how to select instances from different field size integer attribute value
I have a field of instances with a stored integer named attribute. In another field of instances, I want to select only those whose indices match the stored named attribute in the first field. I can eliminate the duplicate numbers in the first field by converting instances to points and then points to curves, using the named attribute as the ID, so they do not count. The named attribute and amount of the instances in the first field could randomly change and the selection should always match.



Upon joining your indices change. So you want to capture "index" as an attribute and sample by that one. Or don't join.

joining is just for visualization, as a result the bottom field should separate instances index nr: 20,1,13,17,11,6,1,20,14

If I get it right, you are expecting to select UV Spheres with index 1, 6, 11, 14, 15, 17 and 20 ?

yes, sorry, there was a mistake in my comment above

this is a naive solution so far IMAGE

convert the cubes to points, move them to <attribute, 0, 0>, now for spheres check if there's a point (proximity) at <index, 0, 0>

@Markus von Broady, thats what figured out already in my comment above, just using "sample nearest" instead proximity - works as I want, but this is a bit mechanical way... thought there could be something more elegant...?

(Using Blender 4.2.4)
This proposal is based on a lookup table, a tool "used to validate input values by matching against a list of valid items in an array". Here:

the input values to validate are the UV Sphere indices,
the valid items are the "rnd" attribute values,
the array is made with a point cloud,
the matching procedure is based on the Geometry Proximity node.

The trick is to use the UV Sphere indices and the "rnd" attribute values as Position, instead of the classical 3D world coordinates. Only the coordinates of the points in the point cloud are modified and replaced by the "rnd" attribute values ; the cubes position is unaffected. The coordinates of the UV Spheres are also unaffected, taking advantage of the Sample Position socket of the Geometry Proximity node to input the Index instead of the geometrical position. A returned Distance of 0 means that there is a "rnd" attribute matching the Index.

Dark pink nodes: Build the lookup table with the query key (here the "rnd" attribute) as Position. A Merge by Distance node is removing duplicates.
Dark green nodes: Query the lookup table using the Index as query key (i.e. as Sample Position). The Distance output by the Geometry Proximity node is 0 if a "rnd" attribute is matching the Index ; it is positive otherwise. Taking advantage of the typecasting between float and boolean, a Not operator is applied to turn 0 distance to True and positive distance to False.
Resources:
(Blender 4.2.4+)

got it now (Markus comment was about this approach as well right?), THANKS

Yes, I imagine this is what Markus has in mind.
